# config ghost blog in production environment

Tags: node.js, iis, ghost-blog

I want config ghost blog in production environment in iis web server.

How i can do this?

Where i must enter this command? according to [Using Environments](http://docs.ghost.org/usage/configuration/)

```
NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js
```

`NODE_ENV` is unknown when i type this command in node command prompt!

Answer (score 0):

If you going to use IIS server to run ghost blog:

1. you need to configure iisnode module.
2. add web.config file and you can specify your environment.

`<handlers>
    <add node_env="production" name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" /></handlers>`

https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config

Comment: Does that answer your question?